# The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, appcmd

I'm getting the following error message:

> The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
>   At line:1 char:7

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for the question to be reasonably answered. The error message is quite clear and informative, you are trying to call appcmd but it cannot be found. Since you still asking, there is something else that is not clear to you. Explain what you are trying to achieve, show your code, say what you are getting instead (you've done this last part). It is much more easier helping, when you can describe a particular problem you are dealing with rather than posting a random error message without any context.

Comment: I am trying to recycle apppool using appcmd, However initially i am getting this error.C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>appcmd
'appcmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0>psexec appcmd
'psexec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Yep, appcmd or psexec cannot be found. It seems pretty clear. You need either to add them to your PATH or specify path to them explicitly.

Answer (score 48):

`Appcmd.exe` exists at the location `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\`. You either need to update your PATH variable to add the path `%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\` like

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\
```

or you can use `Set-Location` to first go to the location of `Appcmd.exe` like

```
Set-Location %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\
```

and then run you command.

OR you can use the following:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe

Answer (score 20):

I think the user has the same problem I did: %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\ was empty on my machine.

You need to "Turn Windows features on and off", and then select "IIS Management Scripts and Tools" under "Internet Information Services"->"Web Management Tools".

Answer (score 9):

Open command prompt as administrator, and try....

```
cd c:\windows\system32\inetsrv
```

then type

```
appcmd
```

see my example below
[image]

vote up if it works for you : D

Comment: This is how you would test if appcmd is in place, but does not help if the tool is in place, but not configured in path

Comment: why the downvote ? you are not correct @WillDud..the steps i provided above explicitly shows you'll need to cd into the location where executable leaves...so no talk of path configuration or not..

Comment: For me, when I run the appcmd from the path you've mentioned, it returns same error: The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,

Answer (score 7):

The issue is not just the path of the file.

Suggestion [3,General]: The command appcmd was not found, but does exist in the current location. Windows PowerShell does not load commands from the current location by default. If you trust this command, instead type ".\appcmd". See "get-help about_Command_Precedence" for more details.

So please run as follows:

```
.\appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /+"[name='Default Web Site'].bindings.[protocol='https',bindingInformation='*:443:']" /commit:apphost
```

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me, this one did.  I checked that appcmd.exe existed in %systemroot%\system32\inetsrv then tried Set-Location.  No dice.  But running `.\appcmd` rather than `appcmd` or `appcmd.exe` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and resolved it by doing the following:

```
$systemRoot = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("systemroot")
Set-Location $systemRoot\system32\inetsrv
.\appcmd
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to manually play with PATH or system env.
The portable solution is to use the full path and name of the command:

For example, to recycle an app pool:

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool /apppool.name:"my website app pool name"
```

Answer (score 0):

To view your current environment paths:

```
$Env:Path
```

To add the APPCMD path:

```
$Env:Path += ";C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\"
```

This should allow you to use your APPCMD command e.g.:

```
Appcmd Set Config /Section:RequestFiltering /AllowHighBitCharacters:True
```