# How to start/stop IIS Website and application pool on another server while deploying my project through Bamboo?

Tags: iis, devops, bamboo

Currently I am using this Powershell script which runs before deployment script.

```
$Password=Convertto-SecureString -String ${bamboo.deploy.password} -AsPlainText -force
$Credentials=New-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ${bamboo.deploy.username},$Password
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName ${Server} -Credential $Credentials
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {start cmd;cd C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv;appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:"${app_pool_name}"}
```

But it gives the following error:

> The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I have also tried using the `Stop-WebAppPool cmdlet`. It also gave an error saying `Stop-WebAppPool` is not recognized as the name of any `cmdlet`. I have also tried Import-Module `WebAdministration` before `Stop-WebAppPool cmdlet`. It also was not successful.

Edit: When I use the same script from my localhost, it works successfully. When I use this script on BAMBOO, it gives the above mentioned error. Is it possible that the `WebAdministration` Module is not installed on the agent's environment or Bamboo server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The term 'appcmd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945542/the-term-appcmd-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet)

Comment: you could try $systemRoot = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("systemroot")
Set-Location $systemRoot\system32\inetsrv
.\appcmd or @cdsln suggested link solution.

Comment: @cdsln I had tried it before posting this query. It didn't work for me.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal It didn't work. The same error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you enabled IIS Management Scripts and Tools feature of iis.

you could try these steps: 
1. Open Turn Windows features on or off.

2. Enable IIS Management Scripts and Tools under “Internet Information Services” => “Web Management Tools”.
3. We will see the appcmd.exe in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv folder then.
4. Add C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv to PATH system environment variable.